# How to choose k for MAP@K?

Tags: model-evaluation, precision-recall, recommender-system

Scenario: We want to evaluate our recommender system, which recommends items to potential customers when visiting a product detail page.

Here are actual relevant items:

```
Customer 1: Item1, Item2
Customer 2: Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6, Item7
Customer 3: Item8
.....
```

Suppose the max number of actual relevant items per customer is 5(i.e. Customer 2).

Should I set K = 5 if we want to use MAP@K as the evaluation metric?

Comment: Business reasons.

Comment: For what reason do you want to use this metric? What of value to you does it measure?